# Create new tables or use the native in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.5

I need to write a component that have a per profile page where the user can add articles,

and i dont know if I need to create a new table for users, articles, user_articles, or use the native joomla tables??

and if yes how can I override the methods JFactory::getUser(); - and others...

and if yes will i have to create own methods to save sessions, or use the native $user->is_guest() ???, i am confused about that.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could go about this.

First, you really don't need any new tables at all. There isn't any information you need that isn't already being saved in either the user or article tables. If you want to use Joomla articles, then you would need a new view and model for com_content that displays articles by article author. Use the built in front end content entry and make users register before they can submit articles.

The other option is to switch to using K2 for your content display. K2 already has article by author built in so you wouldn't need to do anything. Again, use the built in front end content entry and require registration before submission.